# spaCy, preparing training data: doc.char_span returning 'None'

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I'm following the instructions in spaCy's documentation to prepare my own training data ([here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data)).

My problem begins at this line:

```
span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
```

For entities which I'm labelling as an organization ('ORG'), it seems to work fine i.e. it returns a span object. However, for entities which I'm labelling as money ('MONEY'), it returns a None object.

Here's two examples from my training set:

```
('Payments from the Guardian, Kings Place, 90 York Way, London N1 9GU, for articles:', [(18, 26, 'ORG')]) // Returns a span object for 'Guardian'

('24 July 2020, received Â£100. Hours: 1 hr. (Registered 02 February 2021)', [(24, 28, 'MONEY')]) // Returns None for '£100'
```

Note: the Â appears in the console, but it's not in the original json text file. Leaving it in in case it's somehow part of the issue

Does anyone please have any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

[I'm very new to spacy (started learning last week), so please ELI5!]

**UPDATE: As it seems the Â could be the problem, below is how I'm loading the data. How do I get rid of the Â's? (which aren't visible in the original file)**

```
with open('training_data.json') as train_data:
    train_data_json = json.load(train_data)
```

Comment: Yes, the Â symbol is causing the problem. possibly change the encoding format for how you are loading the data or strip out any unwanted symbols

Comment: When you say the As aren't visible in the original file, what are you viewing it in that they don't appear? And is the symbol £ with no A or something else?

Comment: I'm viewing them in notepad and in visual code studio. The symbol is £ with no A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an encoding problem when opening the file. The context for information extraction on `tags` of type `MONEY` is not working most likely do to this issue since the start of the token is not `£`.

It is not clear what encoding the file is using so try some of the most common ones first which are `utf-8`, `iso-8859-1`, `latin1`

```
with open('training_data.json', encoding='utf-8')
    # your logic here
```

replace the `encoding` with other potential candidates

Comment: Thank you! encoding utf-8 fixed it.

Comment: a little unfair to accept this answer considering mine came first having installed spacy to identify your issue. along with my comment suggesting the updated indices and encoding 4 hours before this answer

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers have pointed out, you have an encoding issue that you need to resolve. We can't say what encoding your file is without seeing it. Normally on Linux you can use the `file` command to check encoding (not perfect, but pretty good), but JSON is supposed to always be UTF8, so that won't help here. If you have access to the pre-JSON data source you might want to check that.

However besides that, the issue is that `char_span` returns `None` if your span is invalid, that is, if your character indices don't align with token boundaries. For example, if you wanted to mark "Tokyo" in the "Tokyo Tower is..." example, but gave character indices 0 and 4 ("Toky"), you'd get `None`.

In this case it sounds like you have a systematic error that needs fixing, but if a small number of annotations are bad, there are options you can pass to the function to tell it to expand or contract if the alignment is off instead. Check [the docs](https://spacy.io/api/doc#char_span) for more details.

Comment: Adding encoding = utf-8 to the with open() fixed it! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The Â symbol is causing the problem. When it is present `span` returns `None` as you correctly pointed out.

Training data for testing (*note the updated indices for 'MONEY' annotation*):

```
train = [("Tokyo Tower is 333m tall.", [(0, 11, "BUILDING")]),
        ('Payments from the Guardian, Kings Place, 90 York Way, London N1 9GU, for articles:', [(18, 26, 'ORG')]),
        ('24 July 2020, received £100. Hours: 1 hr. (Registered 02 February 2021)', [(23, 27, 'MONEY')])]
```

Code from the spacy docs you shared:

```
db = DocBin()
for text, annotations in train:
    doc = nlp(text)
    for start, end, label in annotations:
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
        print(span)
```

Output:

```
Tokyo Tower
Guardian
£100
```

Comment: Thank you. The Â isn't in the original json file, but it appears later in the console. Do you know how I get rid of it, if it isn't even in the original file?

(I'll add some code to show how I'm loading the data.)

Comment: Can't really offer a solution without access to the file as you say this character isn't actually appearing. You can specify the encoding `with open('training_data.json', encoding='utf-8')`. Try opening the json file and resaving etc.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! All of the cash sums are being returned as span types now.