# spacy doc.char_span raises error whenever there is any number in string

Tags: python, json, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I was trying to train a model from spacy. I have strings and their token offsets saved into the JSON file.

I have read that file using `utf-8` encoding and there is no special character in it. But it raises `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

```py
# code for reading file
with open("data/results.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    training_data = json.loads(file.read())
```

I have also tried changing `alignment_type` from `strict` to `contract` & `expand`. The `expand` works but shows incorrect spans.

```py
span = doc.char_span(start, end, label, alignment_mode="contract")
```

The code that I'm using

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
db = DocBin()
training_dataset = [[
        "Department of Chemistry,Central University of Las Villas,Santa Clara,Villa Clara,54830,Cuba.",
        [
            [
                57,
                68,
                "city_name"
            ],
            [
                87,
                91,
                "country_name"
            ]
        ]
    ]]
for text, annotations in training_dataset:
    doc = nlp(text)
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annotations:
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label)
        ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents
    db.add(doc)
```

I have pasted the JSON object that is read from the file, directly into the program for debugging purposes.

When I tried after removing the `54830,` part, the program runs successfully.

I have also referred to this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976538/spacy-preparing-training-data-doc-char-span-returning-none), but that issue has a special character. But this string doesn't have any special character.

Can anyone know why this is happening with all strings that contain a number in them?

Comment: Which Spacy version are you using? Have you tried with the latest one?

Comment: @J.Ferrarons
I'm using spacy version 3.4.3 on my system and it's the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` occurs in line `doc.ents = ents` when one of the entries in `ents` is `None`.

The reason for having a `None` in the list is that `doc.char_span(start, end, label)` returns `None` when the `start` and `end` provided don't align with token boundaries.

The tokenizer of the model (`spacy.blank("en")`) doesn't behave as needed for this use case. It seems that it doesn't produce an end of token after a comma  that follows a number without space after the comma.

Examples:

Tokenizing a number with decimals:

```py
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.blank("en")
>>> nlp.tokenizer.explain("5,1")
[('TOKEN', '5,1')]
```

**One** single token.

Tokenizing a number + comma + letter:

```py
>>> nlp.tokenizer.explain("5,a")
[('TOKEN', '5,a')]
```

**One** single token.

Tokenizing a letter + comma + letter:

```py
>>> nlp.tokenizer.explain("a,a")
[('TOKEN', 'a'), ('INFIX', ','), ('TOKEN', 'a')]
```

**Three** tokens.

Tokenizing a number + comma + space + letter:

```py
>>> nlp.tokenizer.explain("5, a")
[('TOKEN', '5'), ('SUFFIX', ','), ('TOKEN', 'a')]
```

**Three** tokens.

Tokenizing a number + comma + space + number:

```py
>>> nlp.tokenizer.explain("5, 1")
[('TOKEN', '5'), ('SUFFIX', ','), ('TOKEN', '1')]
```

**Three** tokens.

Therefore, with the default tokenizer, a space is needed after a comma following a number so the comma is used to create the token boundaries.

Workarounds:

- Preprocess your text to add a space after the commas you desire to split tokens by. This would also require to update the `start` and `end` values of the annotations.
- Create your custom tokenizer as described in Spacy documentation: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Haven't thought about this. This resolved my issue.